# How to nest a SELECT into a UPDATE statement in PL/pgSQL

Tags: postgresql, select, sql-update, plpgsql

I have the below code which works well, the problem is I am creating a table each time, which means I need to recreate all indexes and delete the old tables when the new ones have been created.

```
DO
$do$
DECLARE
    m   text;
    arr text[] := array['e09000001','e09000007','e09000033','e09000019'];
BEGIN
    FOREACH m IN ARRAY arr
    LOOP
        EXECUTE format($fmt$
            CREATE TABLE %I AS
            SELECT a.ogc_fid,
                   a.poly_id,
                   a.title_no,
                   a.wkb_geometry,
                   a.distcode,                 
                   SUM(COALESCE((ST_Area(ST_Intersection(a.wkb_geometry, b.wkb_geometry))/ST_Area(a.wkb_geometry))*100, 0)) AS aw
            FROM %I a
                LEFT OUTER JOIN filter_ancientwoodlands b ON
                    ST_Overlaps(a.wkb_geometry, b.wkb_geometry) OR ST_Within(b.wkb_geometry, a.wkb_geometry)
            GROUP BY a.ogc_fid,
                     a.poly_id,
                     a.title_no,
                     a.wkb_geometry,
                     a.distcode;
        $fmt$, m || '_splitv2_aw', m || '_splitv2_distcode');
    END LOOP;
END
$do$
```

Instead I would like to just create a new column in the existing table and update it. I have done this with simple queries like:

```
ALTER TABLE e09000001 ADD COLUMN area double precision;
UPDATE e09000001 SET area=ST_AREA(wkb_geometry);
```

I am having a lot of trouble figuring out to use UPDATE and SET with my more complicated SELECT statement above. Does anyone know how I can achieve this?

**UPDATE:** So I tried doing what @abelisto suggested:

```
UPDATE test_table
SET aw = subquery.aw_temp
FROM (SELECT SUM(COALESCE((ST_Area(ST_Intersection(a.wkb_geometry, b.wkb_geometry))/ST_Area(a.wkb_geometry))*100, 0)) AS aw_temp
            FROM test_table a
                LEFT OUTER JOIN filter_ancientwoodlands b ON
                    ST_Overlaps(a.wkb_geometry, b.wkb_geometry) OR ST_Within(b.wkb_geometry, a.wkb_geometry)
            GROUP BY a.ogc_fid,
                     a.poly_id,
                     a.title_no,
                     a.wkb_geometry,
                     a.distcode) AS subquery;
```

But the query just runs for a long time (going one an hour) when it should only take a few seconds. Can anyone see an error in my code?

Comment: It seems that you looking for `update ... from ...` form. Look at the documentation about `update` statement for details: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-update.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a `WHERE` clause to join the `from` expression to the `update` table.

perhaps like this.

```
UPDATE test_table
SET aw = subquery.aw_temp
FROM (SELECT SUM(COALESCE((ST_Area(ST_Intersection(a.wkb_geometry, b.wkb_geometry))/ST_Area(a.wkb_geometry))*100, 0)) AS aw_temp,a.wkb_geometry
            FROM test_table a
                LEFT OUTER JOIN filter_ancientwoodlands b ON
                    ST_Overlaps(a.wkb_geometry, b.wkb_geometry) OR ST_Within(b.wkb_geometry, a.wkb_geometry)
            GROUP BY a.ogc_fid,
                     a.poly_id,
                     a.title_no,
                     a.wkb_geometry,
                     a.distcode) AS subquery
WHERE
    subquery.wkb_geometry = test_table.wkb_geometry;
```